# preserve string value doing text() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this **string**

```
<div>
   <p class="pagi">page 1 content</p> 
   <p class="pagi">page 2 content</p>
   <p class="pagi">page 3 content</p>
</div>
```

I want to wrap `pagi` with `pagiWrap` but in the same time I want to preserve the html tag.

This won't work

```
var $pagi= $(str).find('.pagi');
var html= '<div id="#main-wrapper">';
$pagi.each(function() {
  html+= '<div class="pageWrap">' + $(this).text() + '</div>';
});
html+= '</div>';
```

Because The html tag will be gone. If I do `.html()`, it will render altogether with my wrapper which I don't want.

I've also tried `htmlDecode($(this).html())` it doesn't work. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method and do something like this.

```js
var str = '<div><p class="pagi">page 1 content</p><p class="pagi">page 2 content</p><p class="pagi">page 3 content</p></div>';

var pagi = $(str)
  // wrap the outer div
  .wrap('<div id="main-wrapper"></div>')
  // get pagi
  .find('.pagi')
  // wrap it
  .wrap('<div class="pageWrap"></div>')
  // get the wrapped element
  .closest('.pageWrap')
  // update the text content by its html content
  .text(function() {
    return $(this).html()
  })
  // get outer wrapper by id
  .closest('#main-wrapper')
  // get html content from DOM object
  [0].outerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML = pagi;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

You can also use [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method here.

```js
var str = '<div><p class="pagi">page 1 content</p><p class="pagi">page 2 content</p><p class="pagi">page 3 content</p></div>';

var pagi = $(str)
  // wrap the outer div
  .wrap('<div id="main-wrapper"></div>')
  // get pagi
  .find('.pagi')
  // replace the elements
  .replaceWith(function() {
    // generate element which is to be placed
    // instead of current element
    return $('<div/>', {
      class: "pageWrap",
      // set the text as the html content
      text: this.outerHTML
    });
  })
  // back to the cached previous selector
  .end()
  // get outer wrapper by id or use .parent()
  .closest('#main-wrapper')
  // get html content from DOM object
  [0].outerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML = pagi;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have multiple .pagi sir.

Comment: If I append your content it will be html, I want `<p class="pagi">page 1 content</p>` to be output as unescaped content, that's why I need to wrap it so that I still can select them.

Comment: you have multiple `;;` is that a typo?

Comment: @NatelyJamerson : yes I just removed

Comment: genius, didn't know text() has a callback function

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.pagi').parent('div').text($('.pagi').parent('div').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="pagi">page 1 content</p>
  <p class="pagi">page 2 content</p>
  <p class="pagi">page 3 content</p>
</div>
```

use `.text()` with `.html()`

Comment: how bout my #main-wrapper?

Comment: @NatelyJamerson can you explain a bit more about the main wrapper i thought you only want to wrap the class pagi?what about the main wrapper?

Comment: hey how can u select string?

Comment: @guradio no need for each loop.

Comment: @Jai my thoughts is he wants to wrap each class with class pagiWrap i will add another one where all of the p are in one wrapper.

Comment: No No. I <p class="pagi">page 2 content</p> can be output as unrendered html, that's why I need to wrap it.

Comment: @NatelyJamerson can you check answer if this is what you want

Comment: @guradio ur answer output 3 `<p>`, I want the html tag to be visible for the user.

Comment: the html tag of p?ok let me make it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting with the element you wish to be the "wrapper" and work inward. Using the jQuery [`.wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method to enclose your html.

```
// create wrapper element
var wrapper = $('<div id="#main-wrapper" />');
var str = '<div><p class="pagi">page 1 content</p><p class="pagi">page 2 content</p><p class="pagi">page 3 content</p></div>';
// set the wrappers html, then find our pagi elements and wrap each
wrapper.html(str).find('.pagi').wrap('<div class="pagiWrap" />');
// now set the pagiWrap elements text to their current html
wrapper.find('.pagiWrap').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).html());
})
// output wrapper
$('#output').html(wrapper);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bgugq70c/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Why do you make things so complicated? Remember: *jQuery - write less, do more*?
The way I see this is, you can do it with a simple

```
$('.pagi').wrap('<div class="pagewrap">');
```

see here in my snippet:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.pagi').wrap('<div class="pagewrap">');
  console.log($('#outer').html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
   <p class="pagi">page 1 content</p> 
   <p class="pagi">page 2 content</p>
   <p class="pagi">page 3 content</p>
</div>
```

The console output was only added to show the result as html code.